# Runs in step into but not run sub

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub shear_curve()


'Loop Through the folder
excFolder = "C:\Users\User\Desktop\BH-2022-FS01-1\test\"
excFile = Dir(excFolder & "*.xls")
Do While excFile <> ""
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(excFolder & excFile)
       
    Bhid = wb.Sheets(1).Range("D4")
    Debug.Print (Bhid)
    Workbooks("Detailed Master List - TNB Substation").Sheets(2).Activate
    rownum = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Bhid, Range("B:B"), 0)
    Debug.Print (rownum)
    Range("B" & rownum).Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert
    Range("B" & rownum).Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert
    Range("B" & rownum).Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert
    
    wb.Sheets(1).Range("G9:G12").Copy
    Workbooks("Detailed Master List - TNB Substation").Sheets(2).Activate
    Range("AP" & rownum & ":AP" & rownum + 3).PasteSpecial xlValues
        
    wb.Close savechanges:=False
    
   
    excFile = Dir()
Loop
End Sub
```

my code here works perfectly fine when I step into line by line but when I run my code in run sub(F5) the code break. can anyone help?

Comment: Make sure all of your `Range` objects are fully qualified with the worksheet that they are from. If you don't do that, then Excel assumes they are all from the `ActiveSheet`.

Comment: '''
Workbooks("Detailed Master List - TNB Substation").Sheets(2).Activate
rownum = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Bhid, Range("B:B"), 0)

I activate the workbook "Detailed Master List - TNB Substation" in the first row of code here, to make sure the second row of code is looking at the range("B:B") in the  "Detailed Master List - TNB Substation" workbook, am I not right doing this?

Comment: In that example, `Range("B:B")` is referring to whatever sheet is active, not the one from the beginning of the code like you probably expect.

Comment: hey braX, I finally got it to work, thanks!